# Error in Jenkins Gradle builds. NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)

Tags: jenkins, gradle, proxy, ntlm

I am building a gradle project in Jenkins. 
I have used Jenkins extensively earlier, but with maven and without corporate proxy.

Scenario:
1) Systems behind corp proxy
2) A gradle project with gradle wrapper for build.
3) Working Jenkins Master( Linux based)
4) A gradle.properties file with complete proxy details.

So in this scenario, as we have a proxy, I have created gradle.properties with necessary proxy details and triggered jenkins build.
But I am seeing this error( or warning) in the jenkins build log.
**The build compiles successfully and creates a jar file.**

Any idea on why this is happening and any workarounds / solution.

I have checked this, but the solutions are not working. [Gradle issue](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/1-4-rc-1-gradle-dependencies-results-in-endless-loop-stating-authentication-error/2527/20)

**Contents of my gradle.properties.**

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=somehost    
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080    
systemProp.http.proxyUser=username    
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=somepasswrd    
systemProp.https.proxyHost=somehost     
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080    
systemProp.https.proxyUser=username    
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=somepasswrd    
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1      
systemProp.http.keepAlive = true
```

[image]

Comment: I am facing same issue. Did you find any solution for this? I would be thankful to you.

Comment: same issue.....

Comment: No. I have found out that it is due to proxy and nothing much can be done. It wont cause any issues either.